ResourceCollection does not implicitly transform each item in the collection using the corresponding resource class in Laravel
So I'm following the course: https://youtu.be/YGqCZjdgJJk?si=axa0ZDfO1BOxN-MO&t=1918 and I'm getting the following issue:
I have 2 resources in my Laravel app. The first is provided below
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\V1;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CustomerResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     * 
     * The keys are the property names that we want in the JSON response and we just 
     * provide the values for those properties
     */
    public function toArray($request) //Where the request is the Eloquent model
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "name" => $this->name,
            "type" => $this->type,
            "email" => $this->email,
            "address" => $this->address,
            "city" => $this->city,
            "state" => $this->state,
            "postalCode" => $this->postal_code
        ];
    }
}

The second resource is provided below
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\V1;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class CustomerCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}

In the corresponding "CustomerController.php" file, I have implemented the index() method as shown
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return new CustomerCollection(Customer::all()); //An eloquent query
    }
}

The routing to this controller is provided as shown
Route::group(["prefix" => "v1", "namespace" => "App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1"], function() {
    Route::apiResource("customers", "CustomerController");
    Route::apiResource("invoices", "InvoiceController");
});

When I access the "customers" endpoint, I expect a JSON of all my customers to be returned in the format that I have defined in CustomerResource. However, the code does not work as expected and instead, the endpoint returns all the customer data without the implicit format I have defined for the CustomerResource. What is wrong here and how can I fix it?
What I am trying to do is essentially reproduce the outcome shown in the course that I'm following, here's the link to the course again: https://youtu.be/YGqCZjdgJJk?si=axa0ZDfO1BOxN-MO&t=1918 . Please take a look at the link as I've embedded timestamp to the link which shows the part which I'm trying to replicate. In the video, he didn't modify the CustomerCollection resource after generating it via the command line and he still gets the formatting which he has defined when visiting the "customers" endpoint. I cannot reproduce that in my own code for some reason and I've checked everything aligns with his code including the version he's using (which seems to be Laravel version 8)
If you want to reproduce the problem yourself, here's the git repo to the project that I'm following: https://github.com/blueboy90780/laravel-api-course
For my versions:
PHP: 7.4
Laravel: 8.10
